# Responsive Text Heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, heading

I want to make text heading responsive. As you can see in the [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rvLwcp63/1/), heading is "The Swift List". How can I make words "THE" and "LIST" to stay at the edges of the word "SWIFT"? I have managed to do so in normal screen size, but when I change screen size, it does not remain as before (at the edges of word "SWIFT").

For those who dont want to open in new tab. The code I have written:

**HTML**

```
<p><span class="wordThe">THE</span>
<br><span class="textSwift">SWIFT</span>
<br><span class="wordList">LIST</span>
```

```css
.carInfo {
  background: #05196b;
  height: 291px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 50px;
}
.wordThe {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ff1414;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding-left: 12%;
}
.textSwift {
  padding-left: 24%;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 4.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 0.5;
}
.wordList {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ff1414;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding-left: 67%;
}
.textAtRight {
  text-align: justify;
  direction: rtl;
  clear: both;
  float: right;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="carInfo">
        <p><span class="wordThe">THE</span>
        <br><span class="textSwift">SWIFT</span>
        <br><span class="wordList">LIST</span>
        <span class="textAtRight"><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        <br>Consectetur adipisicing elit
        <br>dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        <br>velit esse cillum dolore eu
        <br>proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add a scrn.shot of the text with exact position that you actually want?

Comment: @Vishnu https://snag.gy/KgPQL8.jpg  - This is how I want to make text with exact position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `pseudo elements` and `data-attributes`

CSS

```
.carInfo {
    background: #05196b;
    height: 291px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 50px;
    text-align:center;
}

.textSwift {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 4.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 0.5;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding:3.5rem 0;
}

.textSwift::before{
  content:attr(data-before);
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ff1414;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.textSwift::after{
  content:attr(data-after);
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ff1414;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}


.textAtRight {
  text-align: justify;
  direction: rtl;
  clear: both;
  float: right;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="carInfo">
        <p>
            <div>
                <span class="textSwift" data-before="THE" data-after="LIST">SWIFT</span>
            </div>

        <span class="textAtRight">
            <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            <br>Consectetur adipisicing elit
            <br>dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
            <br>velit esse cillum dolore eu
            <br>proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        </span>

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

hope this helps..

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/rvLwcp63/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Change the css at the following parts:

```
.wordThe {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ff1414;
  font-size: 4.5vw;
  padding-left: 6vw;
}
.textSwift {
  padding-left: 22vw;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size:6.5vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 0.5;
}
.wordList {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ff1414;
  font-size: 4.5vw;
  padding-left:52vw;
}
```

vw is calculated as 1/100th of your viewport width, which changes dynamically as you resize your screen.similarly you can apply the same for other texts if you want them to be responsive too.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of media queries to help you change the code at different widths.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

What I think you should do is make use of the queries and flexbox to achieve this.

I hope I have somewhat answered your question.  I am visually having a difficult time understanding what it is you want so if I come up with a code example I will share it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new at front end so I don't know much about queries or flexbox. I will look into them.

Comment: Cool beans @ErolAliyev